# String to NSDate vice versa then into a UILabel

Tags: ios, swift

GOAL: I want my string to be date formatted and put inside a label.

Current code:

```
let dateString           = "2015-10-09 17:41:14"
let dateFormatter        = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM d, yyyy | hh:mm a" 
let date                 = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)
//FOUND NIL HERE
let NewString            = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date!)
Date.text                =  NewString
```

The code above works if I do `NSDate()` but not if I use my own string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using wrong date format to convert the string to date and it returns a nil date because of that. First you need to use the exact date format to convert the string to date then set your date formatter style to get it back as string in your desired format.

Change your code like:

```
let dateString           = "2015-10-09 17:41:14"
let dateFormatter        = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
let date                 = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM d, yyyy | hh:mm a"
let resultString         = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date!)
print(resultString) // October 9, 2015 | 05:41 PM
```

Comment: Worked, thank you! I'll accept this as the best answer in a few minutes when stackoverflow allows me to

Comment: Capital is important (MMMM), too. If you missed it you will get nil